# How to bind Windows8.1 searchbox in MVVM way?

Tags: c#, mvvm, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, search-box

I need to implement a SearchBox in a Windows 8.1 Store Application using Mvvm.

I have tried these suggestions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xx130656.aspx#SearchFunctionality

and

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-InputConverter-in-dfd2a81b

But the data is not populating in the View.

Comment: What do you mean "The data is populating in the View"? Did you mean "is not"?

Comment: sorry ..Not populating..corrected the question:)

Comment: What we'll need is: Your data binding XAML and the code with which you fill your collection (based on the search). A quick question: Are you using a `List` or an `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: @NateDiamond I have the same issue, difficulty in trying to understand how to implement SearchBox in pure MVVM way. I am currently using the codebehind to directly call a ViewModel method which returns a list of objects which I then use to populate my SearchBox using AppendQuerySuggestion. Any help to implement it in the right way would be highly appreciated.